# looped return inside forOwn inside map inside render react Componennt

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure if i'm doing well sending inside a lot of returns inside a forOwn (lodash), i try to indent the code accord  ( {{ ( etc, but I'dont see where is my error
I'm using reactv16

```
  return (
    <div className="formSection">
      <button type="button" onClick={() => rowsChildrenValues.push({})}>
        Add Member
      </button>
      {submitFailed && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      {rowsChildrenValues.map((rowValues, index) => {

        return (
          forOwn(Tables[tableCrud].fields[fieldParentKey].subfields, function (fields, fieldKey) {

            return (
              <div className="formSection" key={fieldKey}>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  title="D"
                  onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
                />
                <Field
                  name={fieldKey}
                  type="text"
                  component={FormField}
                  label={fieldKey}
                />
              </div>   
            );
          });   // Here is the error
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

I get this error:

```
./src/components/FormField.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (201:12)

  199 |               </div>
  200 |             );
> 201 |           });
      |             ^
  202 |         );
  203 |       })}
  204 |     </div>
```

Plese if someone can see more the error about the right way to indent this bucle and if sending return like this is correct

UPDATE
I've delete the semicolon and now I get:

Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, phone}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in div

```
 return (
    <div className="formSection">  <-- 176 line
```

2 try:
I've modified my code:

{rowsChildrenValues.map((rowValues, index) =>
      forOwn(Tables[tableCrud].fields[fieldParentKey].subfields, function (fields, fieldKey) {

```
    return (
      <div className="formSection" key={fieldKey}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="D"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
        />
        <Field
          name={fieldKey}
          type="text"
          component={FormField}
          label={fieldKey}
        />
      </div>
    );
  })
```

})}

but I get:

```
./src/components/FormArrayField.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (49:6)

  47 |             );
  48 |           })
> 49 |       })}
     |       ^
  50 |     </div>
  51 |   );
  52 | }
```

Answer (score 0):

where you have commented error ,just take off the semicolon it should work
return(
    
       rowsChildrenValues.push({})}>
        Add Member
      
      {submitFailed && error && {error}}
      {rowsChildrenValues.map((rowValues, index) => {

```
    return (
      forOwn(Tables[tableCrud].fields[fieldParentKey].subfields, function (fields, fieldKey) {

        return (
          <div className="formSection" key={fieldKey}>
            <button
              type="button"
              title="D"
              onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
            />
            <Field
              name={fieldKey}
              type="text"
              component={FormField}
              label={fieldKey}
            />
          </div>   
        );
      })  
    );
  })}
</div>)
```

Comment: thanks , I've thought semicole sure better code in JS !

Comment: can you correct your answer, need to do it with map that contains the forOwn, because i read the value fields of reduxform fieldArray

Comment: thanks, please, I'm getting this error; i've updated my answer

Comment: i think the key that you are setting is an object, instead if you are using react 16 , you dont need to  wrap multiple elements with a parent element https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html

Comment: yes, I've used that already in v16 but i don't realize how i'm wrong with this code, i've udpated again my answer, thanks